# ADT Plugin in Eclipse not working

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I have Eclipse Luna and I am working on Android. The layouts are not getting displayed instead I am getting a message 
" This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of ADT plug-in. Please update ADT plug-in"
I tried Updating ADT even reinstalling it but the Eclipse is giving an error message

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=C__Users_Yash_eclipse_standard-latest-released2_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.ui,1.2.300.v201401292115
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core,1.4.300.v201111030424
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.uriresolver,1.2.100.v201305141800
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.sse.core,1.1.900.v201401101615
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.validation.ui,1.2.500.v201310231530
```

Please help me what should I do???

Comment: Side note: It's highly recommended to use Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADT is deprecated now, so the latest versions of Android tools must not work with it now.
Use Android Studio

Comment: Just out of interest: Is there any other IDE which supports Android ?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA and Android Studio